# Limits and breaks for the first y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is how I am plotting a graph with two y axis. I can add limits and breaks to a secondary axis, how to add limits to a first y axis?

```
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0.001, 0.030), breaks=c(0.001, 0.002, 0.005, 0.010, 0.015, 0.020, 0.030))

p <- ggplot(tmp, aes(x = tmp[, 1])) +
      geom_point(aes(y = tmp[, 2], colour="names(tmp)[2]")) +
      geom_line(aes(y = tmp[, 3]/1500000,colour="names(tmp)[3]")) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0.001, 0.030), breaks=c(0.001, 0.002, 0.005, 0.010, 0.015, 0.020, 0.030)) +
      scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1500000, name = "Coverage", breaks = seq(0, 45000, 5000))) +
      labs(y = "freq",
           x = "position",
           colour = "") +
      scale_colour_hue(labels = c("freq",
                                  "Coverage"),
                       l = 40) +
      ggtitle(names(tmp)[2]) +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(text=element_text(size=12)) +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size =12)) +
      theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.position = "bottom", legend.box = "vertical")
```

Comment: You only need a single `scale_y_continuous()`, the second one is overriding the first one. Just use the first one you have, and add the `sec.axis` argument as you have it in the second y-scale.

Comment: i am not sure I got it...

Comment: you have specified two times `scale_y_continuous`. Delete one or combine both into one like `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0.001, 0.030), breaks=c(0.001, 0.002, 0.005, 0.010, 0.015, 0.020, 0.030), sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1500000, name = "Coverage", breaks = seq(0, 45000, 5000))) +`

Comment: Unfortunately, calls to `scale_*` in ggplot2 are not *additive*, they are *replace-itive* (is that a word?). The point is that `+ scale_quux(.) + scale_quux(.)` does not combine the two calls, only the second is used. This is true for all of `ggplot2`'s scale functions, afaik. (I for one would vote for making them additive, as I've been bitten by this many times.)

Comment: (I can't seem to find a suitable antonym for *additive* that captures this type of behavior ... subtractive isn't right, so I'll stick with *replace-itive*.)

Comment: @r2evans Substitutive? :)

Comment: @r2evans you might be interested in this discussion then: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/4271

Comment: That works well, @ThiagoJacomasso, thanks! If I could easily edit my previous comments without the 5-minute-delete-readd steps, I would ...

Comment: Interesting conversation, thanks @teunbrand. I personally think that allowing additive calls is more generic and intuitive than external calls, but I suspect that it may be non-trivial internally. I know you're more familiar with ggplot2-internals (as well as clauswilke), do you think it's a worthy counter-argument in that discussion? I've been shutdown before with uninformed requests.

Comment: @r2evans The code examples they bring up already show additive calls for scale parameters, which is what you intended, right?

Comment: I think it's slightly different. They're suggesting multiple calls to (e.g.) `scales_params` that are additive. I'm suggesting that multiple calls to `scale_y_continuous` would be additive, warning or erring only when specific properties within the scale are double-assigned/over-written. I think https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/3973#issuecomment-621879755 and https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4268#issuecomment-729224543 confirm that my suggestion to make `scale_*` additive has been discussed in the past and is non-trivial. (Bummer.)